# I am getting the error "Can't assign to Operator"

Tags: python, operator-keyword

I am not sure why it is giving me this error... the part it says is giving me the error is the `previousFirst + previousSecond = previousSecond`. If you are wondering the goal is to print out as many fibonnaci numbers that the user wants to print out.

```
def fibbonaci():
    fibbNumber = input("How many Fibonacci numbers should I print for you?")
    fibbNumber = int(fibbNumber)
    global counter
    counter = 0
    global previousFirst
    previousFirst = 0
    global previousSecond
    previousSecond = 1
    global previousSaved
    previousSaved = 1
    while (counter < fibbNumber):
        previousSaved = previousSecond
        previousFirst + previousSecond = previousSecond
        print (previousFirst)
        print (previousSecond)
        counter += 1

fibbonaci()
```

Comment: As for the bug you were asking about, what did you expect `previousFirst + previousSecond = previousSecond` to do? Assignment always assigns to the thing on the left, not the thing on the right.

Comment: This is my first time coding in over a year, things have changed and I am still getting into the swing of things, my logic here is horrible as well, I cant get it to do what I want, which is to produce the fibonacci numbers in order

Answer (score 1):

1. You have the assignment turned around.  The format is

```
<i>variable</i> = <i>new value</i>
```

so make that:

```
previous_second = previous second + previous_first
```

2. A more normal (non-Python) way to do this is:

```
next = current + previous
previous = current
current = next
```

where "next" is a temporary variable to compute the next in sequence.

3. Python has the ability to do multiple assignments, eliminating the need for temporary variables in this an many other cases.  You can do all of the above with:

```
current, previous = current+previous, current
```

Both computations on the right are done before any assigning happens.  The new value of current is the sum of the old values current+previous, and the new value of previous is the old value of current. Put that in a "for xyz in range(n):" loop, after initializing current=0, previous=1, and you get a loop that works for all non-negative n (including 0).  The final value of current is your result.

4. Its "Fibonacci", not "Fibbonaci", and the guy's real name was Leonardo.

Answer (score 0):

The left hand side of an assignment statement must be a valid name, not an expression. (The `+` is an operator, which means its included in expressions)

This is the line of the culprit, 
`previousFirst + previousSecond = previousSecond`

Also, your code does have a little bit of formatting issues, namely the indentation is bad for the first function. Normally you can get away with this, but being Python, it's part of the language syntax. It also might just be how you copied and pasted it to Stack, take a look at the tips in `How to Edit` and `How to Format` bars, when editing your post.

Comment: I understand, but it is indented properly in my code, when I uploaded it, it formatted differently, I'm unclear on what I need to do to fix it though :(

Comment: @user1861771 Read my answer, you are try messing up the assignment statement.

Answer (score 0):

The line should be

```
previousSecond = previousFirst + previousSecond
```

That's the problem

UPDATE:

There are some logic error to calculate fibbonaci number, the while part coule be:

```
while (counter < fibbNumber):
    previousSaved = previousSecond
    previousSecond = previousFirst + previousSecond
    previousFirst = previousSaved
    print (previousFirst)
    print (previousSecond)
    counter += 1
```